# How do I make webpack generate a single JS file that includes required chunks?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have something like the following entry points:

- page1.tsx
- page2.tsx
- page3.tsx

Some of the files share dependencies so I'm using chunk splitting (with `all` so it splits initial chunks) to have the page specific code be the entry point with some shared chunk files to leverage browser caching.

However, after a lot of searching I cannot find out how to make the resulting `page1.js`, `page2.js` and `page3.js` run on their own assuming they're included via a `<script>` tag. They just sit in limbo expecting me to add the `<script>` tags for the chunks, but since the chunks are dynamic I don't know them beforehand. **I don't want Webpack to do any of the HTML generation** since the scripts are meant to be included on a page provided by a server and for now let's assume I cannot affect that HTML beyond loading `pageN.js`.

So what I'm looking for is a configuration that generates the entry chunk in a way that it will dynamically add `<script>` tags for the chunks (or some other equivalent).